# How to convert json encoded data to array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have a json encoded data stored in my database. I want to convert this json encoded data to array for specific purpose. I have used json_decode function but it seems not working because I got errors. How can I get back to array structure the data I have saved in my database in json format? Please help. Here is my code. Thanks a lot.

**Controller function**

```
function show_at_report(){

      $data = $this->data;
      $report_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $at_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
      $query = $this->core_model->get_report_details($report_id,$at_id);
      $a = $query['rows'];
      var_dump($a);


      foreach($a as $b){
       var_dump($b);
      }

    }
```

Output:

[image]

**Modified Controller function**

```
function show_at_report(){

      $data = $this->data;
      $report_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $at_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
      $query = $this->core_model->get_report_details($report_id,$at_id);
      $a = $query['rows'];
      json_decode($a,TRUE);
      var_dump($a);


      foreach($a as $b){
       json_decode($b,TRUE);
       var_dump($b);
      }

    }
```

**Output showing errors**

[image]

What is the problem with this? How can I get the json data back to array?

Comment: I think you need to loop through `$a` and apply the `json_decode`to each row in the loop.

Comment: `var_dump($a)` or `print_r($a)` to see what is in it.

Comment: Try json_decode($b->data,TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$b` is an array, like the error says, `json_decode` requires a string. And if I'm seeing correctly the variable you really want to decode is `$b[0]->data` as `$b` points to an array with 1 object in it, and that object has a public variable called `data`, this variable contains your json it seems.